# Running totals to be reset on every change of Account number

Tags: sql-server

A Table has data like shown below. It contains data of two account numbers

```
P_ID    AcctNo  Date    Amount
1   111A    04/03/2011  -331
2   111A    04/03/2011  600
3   111A    04/03/2011  20000
4   111A    05/03/2011  -20000
5   111A    10/03/2011  -260
6   111B    01/08/2011  2
7   111B    12/09/2012  500
8   111B    13/09/2012  -166
9   111B    13/09/2012  -225
```

I am looking for a query to give me running totals as shown below (the running totals are reset on the account changing) :

```
P_ID    AcctNo  Date    Amount  Running Total
1   111A    04/03/2011  -331    -331
2   111A    04/03/2011  600     269
3   111A    04/03/2011  20000   20269
4   111A    05/03/2011  -20000  269
5   111A    10/03/2011  -260    9
6   111B    01/08/2011  2       2
7   111B    12/09/2012  500     502
8   111B    13/09/2012  -166    336
9   111B    13/09/2012  -225    111
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: It is 2008 R2.Thanks for the 2012 solution. Will keep it in mind if we migrate to 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :-

```
SELECT P_ID,AcctNo, Amount,
(SELECT SUM(Amount)  as total
    FROM YourTable s 
    WHERE s.P_ID <= a.P_ID and s.AcctNo=a.AcctNo   
 ) AS b
FROM YourTable a
```

Demo in [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/35775/10)

Result

```
╔══════╦════════╦════════╦═══════╗
║ P_ID ║ ACCTNO ║ AMOUNT ║   B   ║
╠══════╬════════╬════════╬═══════╣
║    1 ║ 111A   ║   -331 ║  -331 ║
║    2 ║ 111A   ║    600 ║   269 ║
║    3 ║ 111A   ║  20000 ║ 20269 ║
║    4 ║ 111A   ║ -20000 ║   269 ║
║    5 ║ 111A   ║   -260 ║     9 ║
║    6 ║ 111B   ║      2 ║     2 ║
║    7 ║ 111B   ║    500 ║   502 ║
║    8 ║ 111B   ║   -166 ║   336 ║
║    9 ║ 111B   ║   -225 ║   111 ║
╚══════╩════════╩════════╩═══════╝
```

Answer (score 4):

If you're using SQL Server 2012, it's a very simple query:

```
declare @t table (P_ID int,AcctNo char(4), [Date] date, Amount int)
insert into @t(P_ID,AcctNo,Date,Amount) values
(1,'111A','20110304',-331),
(2,'111A','20110304',600),
(3,'111A','20110304',20000),
(4,'111A','20110305',-20000),
(5,'111A','20110310',-260),
(6,'111B','20110801',2),
(7,'111B','20120912',500),
(8,'111B','20120913',-166),
(9,'111B','20120913',-225)

select *,SUM(Amount) OVER (PARTITION BY AcctNo ORDER BY P_ID
      RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) from @t order by P_ID
```

Result:

```
P_ID        AcctNo Date       Amount      
----------- ------ ---------- ----------- -----------
1           111A   2011-03-04 -331        -331
2           111A   2011-03-04 600         269
3           111A   2011-03-04 20000       20269
4           111A   2011-03-05 -20000      269
5           111A   2011-03-10 -260        9
6           111B   2011-08-01 2           2
7           111B   2012-09-12 500         502
8           111B   2012-09-13 -166        336
9           111B   2012-09-13 -225        111
```

This uses the new ability in SQL Server 2012 for it to apply aggregate functions over ranges - in fact, the [`RANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx) clause isn't even needed in this case, since:

> If `ROWS/RANGE` is not specified but `ORDER BY` is specified, `RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW` is used as default for window frame

But I added it here to make it clearer what was happening.